# Resize 2 Btrfs partition behind luks encryption

Tags: luks, btrfs, resize

I come to you after a non successful research about my issue.

Because I underestimated the size of the root partition, It is now full as ****. Therefore, I want to resize it. Since my /home partition isn't full yet, i want to shrink it and attribute the new space to the /root.

Here is a look of my configuration :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/Tarroot$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL,HCTL
NAME                       FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT                    LABEL       MODEL            HCTL
loop0                      squashfs      1.8G /rofs                                                      
loop1                      squashfs     87.9M /snap/core/5662                                            
loop2                      squashfs    140.9M /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70                                   
loop3                      squashfs      2.3M /snap/gnome-calculator/238                                 
loop4                      squashfs       13M /snap/gnome-characters/124                                 
loop5                      squashfs     14.5M /snap/gnome-logs/45                                        
loop6                      squashfs      3.7M /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57                              
loop7                      squashfs     42.1M /snap/gtk-common-themes/701                                
sda                                    238.5G                                           LITEON L8H-256V2 2:0:0:0
├─sda1                     vfat          512M                                                            
├─sda2                     ext2          244M                                                            
└─sda3                     crypto_LUKS 237.8G                                                            
  └─crypt1                 LVM2_member 237.8G                                                            
    ├─Tarkovski--vg-root   btrfs          28G /media/Tarroot                                             
    ├─Tarkovski--vg-swap_1 swap          7.9G                                                            
    └─Tarkovski--vg-home   btrfs       201.9G /media/Tarroot/home                                        
sdb                                     14.3G                                           Ultra Fit        0:0:0:0
└─sdb1                     vfat         14.3G /cdrom                        UBUNTU 18_1
```

As you can see, i am using a ubuntu live (18.10).
You can see that on sda3 I have Luks encryption, then lvm, then my partitions. And yes, i am a big fan of Tarkovsky, if you don't know him, you must go checkout his movies.

I successfully shrink the /home directory after mounted with this command:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem resize -10G /media/Tarroot/home/
```

After wath i can see the size changed with

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/Tarroot$ sudo btrfs filesystem show -d
Label: none  uuid: 8bb040f7-08e8-43b0-a95c-405f00bd8a23
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 27.13GiB
    devid    1 size 27.94GiB used 27.94GiB path /dev/mapper/Tarkovski--vg-root

Label: none  uuid: bd4ae1da-0da6-4366-a727-d0ff982888f0
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 82.42GiB
    devid    1 size 191.89GiB used 106.02GiB path /dev/mapper/Tarkovski--vg-home
```

But when I try to add the freed space to my root :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/Tarroot$ sudo btrfs filesystem resize +1G /media/Tarroot
Resize '/media/Tarroot' of '+1G'
ERROR: unable to resize '/media/Tarroot': no enough free space
```

That is what I don't understand.

So if you could help me with this it would be great.

I mostly followed this guide : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
After a good night of sleep, I finale understood that i was idiot.
If like me you are stuck with this.
The step are : 
First your mount everything (cf the guide)
Then you shrink the filesystem,
then you shrink the lvm volume,
then you resize the other lvm volume,
finaly the other filesystem.

Thx